# Return type is object where key is computed from argument

Tags: typescript, return-type

Below I have a function `getEntityPropId` and it returns a object with one prop, like `{ 'thingId': 1 }` the string `thing` is passed into the function.

I am curious as to how I can have the function return type include the key `thingId` and not just any string, because I am passing in everything needed to know the return.

However I get this:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)

```
export const getEntityPropId = (value: any, entity: string): { [`${entity}Id`]: number } | null => {
  const id = getEntityId(value, entity)
  if (id !== null) return { [`${entity}Id`]: id }
  return id
}
```

I'd be ok having to setup an `enum` if necessary.

```
enum EntityPropIds {
  thing = 'thingId',
}

export const getEntityPropId = (value: any, entity: EntityPropIds): { [EntityPropIds[entity]]: number } | null => {
  const id = getEntityId(value, entity)
  if (id !== null) return { [EntityPropIds[entity]]: id }
  return id
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic property names on a type-level are not yet possible in TypeScript (although there is an [open issue in discussion on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754))

However, as you've suggested, if you create a type to map entity to entityId, it is possible:

```js
interface EntityIdMapping {
  thing: 'thingId';
}

export const getEntityPropId = <T extends keyof EntityIdMapping>(value: any, entity: T): {[P in EntityIdMapping[T]]: number} | null => {
  const id = getEntityId(value, entity)
  if (id !== null) return { [`${entity}Id`]: id }
  return id
}
```

Instead of an enum I'm using a interface, because those are a little easier to deal with and don't introduce any runtime code.

Next I've added a generic type for the `entity` argument, which must be a key of the mapping interface.

For the return value we're using a mapped type which loops over all types in `EntityIdMapping[T]`. In case of `T = 'thing'`, this only returns one entry for the matching property in the interface.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAngSQCYCycADsaAObIDeAUMsjAPaMBcyA5E4-uwNx3IARnCht2wqD34BfGjVCRYiFACUIYAK5QQANTgAbDRAA8AFWQQAHpBB4AzsjtgoFAHzUBptiA0BbQdA0sjRWxIxQYMgIjCBOyOTq6GCYWAAKUIzE+MgAvMhmFtYQtg4A1hBYjDBoGNj4RKRuABQAbgZGbHAgWAA0FrVYbKYAlGxUANqpyKA1yXWEJGQg5OOmALpr3n4BUNLIAD7IPvr6ue609NGxkcB4ucgALABMAsDVTbfIAIQ5ecf6w2QUHUWhA1GQ4wABgASKjFOZYaT4SGbaZ3PZwBxdLACYGabRooJyfTqIEQOwafSRPIJMBJFLpTL4JpUaR9TjMdjDfjAilUr4AOi4+CAA)

Comment: Note that given the enum `EntityPropIds` you can define something like `type EntityIdMapping = typeof EntityPropIds` so you don't have to specify it twice.