# Return type where one of the keys is computed from parameter in TypeScript 4.1

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to create a function like:

```js
  private isType<G>(type: unknown, property: string): type is { [property]: G } {
    if(blah) return true;
    return false;
  }
```

Where it would be called like

```js
if (this.isType<User[]>(result, 'users') {
  result.users = [UserMock()]
}
```

However, when doing this I get the error at `{ [property]: G }` in `isType`:

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
```

I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57790755/6100005 , and they mention [TypeScript/12754](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754).  Apparently this feature has been [merged](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) in for TypeScript 4.1. So if this question could be answered in the context of how to do this in TypeScript 4.1 I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: The return type of the isType should be boolean?

Comment: It is a boolean.  `if (blah) return true; else return false`

Comment: I'm not sure such kind of feature could be implemented in TS. How can TS know the value of [property] ? Feature You are talking about is not merged to TS.

Comment: There's no simple way to implement the function to be able to check if the field is `G`.

Comment: Could you make the code here into a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly what you're doing without any extraneous errors?  Obviously `blah` is not part of a real example; could you change it into something that at least shows an attempt to implement the function?  I'm trying to understand if you're talking about a TS type system issue or an issue with the JS code that is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

`{ [property]: G }` is not a valid type because of the error that you've posted here about using variables as property keys.

In order to make a valid `type is` return statement, we need to know the `type`, not value, of `property`.  So we need a second generic.  Of course your example is lacking info on where `G` comes from or how it relates to `property`, so you might be able to refine this a bit.  But basically you want something like this:

```
function isType<G, P extends PropertyKey>(type: unknown, property: P): type is { [K in P]: G } {
    if(blah) return true;
    return false;
  }
```